# Grouped data with unix time stamp by day for in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to return group a dataset in my db by day but the data come out rough and not how we expect.

```
SELECT time, price 
FROM chart_data 
WHERE time >= ?
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') 
ORDER BY time ASC
```

Is there a better way to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean "rough"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `GROUP BY` expression in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')  as day,
       MAX(price)
FROM chart_data 
WHERE time >= ?
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day ASC;
```

Note:  This adds an aggregation function to `price`.  I'm not sure what you want, but `MAX()` seems reasonable.